# Pre-processing OpenStreetMap upload to support tag with colon?

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I want to upload some point features for trees to [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) (with the tag `natural=tree`, see [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dtree)).

I typically would use [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) to do this type of update. But, is there an easy way for me to pre-process my data so that the `species:en` field is recognized? Shapefile fields cannot have colons.

My typical workflow is basically this:

- prepare my data (shapefile) in QGIS
- open the file in JOSM
- (make adjustments in JOSM)
- upload data

Answer (score 0):

Since the field name cannot have a colon, use a similar placeholder field name in the pre-processed data set. Then, in JOSM:

- Select all of your data features.
- Then, edit the tag. The data values will stay intact.

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/eric_czajkowski/status/887496648896782336) helped me with this solution.